# Cannot use IN operator in Javascript when looping through JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a Json response, it looks like this:

```
[{
        "item": "1",
        "addr": "someaddr"
    },
    {
        "item": "2",
        "addr": "someotheraddr"
    }
]
```

How can i loop through this record and print, let's say, the `addr` field of each one?

I tried the following:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "someurl",
    type: 'get'
    success: function (data) {         
      $.each(data, function(key, val) {
            console.log(key, val)
        });

      alert("Success");
    }
});
```

But it throws the following error: `TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length'`
I'm sure it's because i'm not properly looping throught the Json Data. Can someone point me out where i'm breaking the loop?

Edit: the Json response is retrieved from an API endpoint using Jquery.

Comment: That's not valid JSON. If it's supposed to be an array, it needs `[]` around it and `,` between them.

Comment: Also, strings need to be in double quotes, not single quotes.

Comment: You also need to specify `dataType: 'json'` in your `$.ajax` call.

Comment: You only need to specify `dataType: 'json'` if the server fails to set the correct `Content-Type` response header.

Comment: @Quentin If the server set the Content-type, he wouldn't get that error, so you need it.

Comment: @Barmar — Since it isn't JSON anyway…

Comment: And if you just want to print the addr field, use `val.addr`

Comment: @Quentin That might just be bad transcription into the question. If it's actually what the server is sending, using `dataType: 'json'` will make it produce an error in the console.

Comment: It's actually a bad transcription, i did not paste that part because the core of the question was looping through the json object, not wheter or not it is json - it is json

Comment: Your loop is fine. The error is because you're not parsing the JSON into an array, so `data` is a string.

Comment: Ok! Thanks @Barmar, but how should i parse it into an array? Using Json.parse?

Comment: https://jsonlint.com/?code=

Comment: I told you earlier: `dataType: 'json'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `dataType: 'json'` to tell jQuery to parse the response as JSON (if the server doesn't send `Content-type: application/json`).

```
$.ajax({
    url: "someurl",
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {         
      $.each(data, function(key, val) {
            console.log(key, val.addr)
        });

      alert("Success");
    }
});
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202758/discussion-on-answer-by-barmar-cannot-use-in-operator-in-javascript-when-looping).

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be that you're not passing back a JSON object, you're passing back individual lines of JSON.   So if you have control over your JSON response, you should make the json look like this:

```
[
  {"item": 1, "addr": "someaddr"},
  {"item": 2, "addr": "someotheraddr"}
]
```

(note that it is wrapped in an array, has commas between each line, and has double quotes around the strings).

Then you can use your each function.  I have included a snippet below that you can try it out with.

```js
var data = [
{"item": 1, "addr": "someaddr"},
{"item": 2, "addr": "someotheraddr"}
];


       
$.each(data, function(key, val) {
  console.log(val.addr)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: He would get an error in `JSON.parse()` if the server weren't passing back valid JSON.

Comment: He said in a comment that he didn't copy the JSON properly into the question.

Comment: My fault for not specifying. The Json response is retrieved from an API